# How to make the same app run after I stop and start playing sound via the headphones?

Tags: applications, settings

I have a problem with playing audio on my Samsung phone. I use wireless headphones with it, I can start and stop playing audio via headphones. I can stop audio for any app that is playing at the moment, but then, when I try to start it again the phone starts another app. There seems to be an app with the highest "priority", it always starts when I start playing sound via bluetooth headphones or via bluetooth of my car.

So, it happens the following way:

- the music app is playing
- I tap "stop" on the headphones - music stops
- I tap "start" on the headphones - audiobooks app is started

My phone: `Samsung Galaxy M30s`

Android version: `10`

App, that overrides any other: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer&hl=en&gl=US